# C++ preprocessor search path search order

Tags: c++, c, standards

Is the `#include` order guaranteed by the standard to be the order of the -I options in the invocation:

example:

having the folders and files:

```
A/foo.h
B/foo.h
```

can it be guaranteed that

```
#include <foo.h>
```

when cpp is invoqued with

```
... -I A -I B ...
```

will choose `A/foo.h` ?

Comment: Note SO is a more appropriate site for this question, for even though it asks about the standard, answers will be at the tool level.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, because an implementation doesn't have to take command line options. § 16.2.2 states for the angle form (or system header inclusion; there isn't a standard name I'm aware of (sound off in the comments)), the preprocessor:

> searches a sequence of implementation-defined places for a header identified uniquely by the specified sequence between the < and > delimiters

The header doesn't even need to be a file.

Specific compilers may make this guarantee. The [g++ manual](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-6.2.0/gcc/Directory-Options.html#index-I-1160), for example, states:

> If you use more than one -I option, the directories are scanned in left-to-right order; the standard system directories come after.

Comment: Thanks. In my particular case I'm using two compilers (one of them g++) and both behave this way. I just wanted to know if this is standard or just by chance.

Comment: @ToniHomedesiSaun: Not really just by chance, but a quality of implementation issue that the standard doesn't try to address.